perl debugger and utf8 variable names
I'm having troubles debugging a Perl program where variable names (or hash key) are UTF-8 strings. The program compiles ok (and runs) but whenever I want to debug it, the debugger is quite unhappy with the variable/hash key names if I need to use them.
Here is a (very simple) MWE:
use strict;

use utf8;
use warnings  qw(FATAL utf8);
use open      qw(:std :encoding(UTF-8));
use charnames qw(:full :short);

my $unité = 125;
my %hash = ( 'Quantité' => 18 );

printf "%d\n", $unité*$unité;
printf "%d\n", $hash{Quantité};


When running, no problem :
$ perl test.pl 
15625
18

But when debugging, the debugger is very sad :
$ perl -d test.pl

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.77
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

            HistFile = '/home/XXX/.perldb.hist'
Éxécution afterinit
main::(test.pl:10):     my $unité = 125;
  DB<100> n
main::(test.pl:11):     printf "%d\n", $unité*$unité;
  DB<100> p $unité
Unrecognized character \xC3; marked by <-- HERE after T}   $unit<-- HERE near column 120 at (eval 10)[/usr/lib64/perl5/5.38/perl5db.pl:742] line 2.
 at (eval 10)[/usr/lib64/perl5/5.38/perl5db.pl:742] line 2.
        eval 'no strict; ($@, $!, $^E, $,, $/, $\\, $^W) = @DB::saved;package main; $^D = $^D | $DB::db_stop;
print {$DB::OUT}   $unité;
' called at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.38/perl5db.pl line 742
        DB::eval called at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.38/perl5db.pl line 3451
        DB::DB called at test.pl line 11

So, how can I access an UTF8-named variable (same problem with the hash key)?

maybe related to: https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/9867 ?

@jhnc, No. That's not even a problem with the debugger.

Maybe this is a silly question, but have you considered not using those characters for variable names? I'm Swedish, but I would never consider naming a variable $fönster (window) for example.

@TLP : you are right, I'm usually reluctant to use UTF8 in variable names and the like. But here, we are getting accented field names from a database (as hashkeys), so quite hard to avoid.

@NdC Oh, that sounds really bad. You are taking hashkeys and making them into variable names? E.g. $hash{"unité"} becomes $unité? That is not something you should be doing. And that is the question you should have asked instead. Show that code and ask how to fix it.

Have you set the debuggers input layer correctly?
The debugger has its own in/out handles named $DB::IN and $DB::OUT
For me setting the :utf8 layer for $DB::IN works (with a utf-8 terminal):
main::(test.pl:10): my $unité = 125;
  DB<1> n
main::(test.pl:11): my %hash = ( 'Quantité' => 18 );
  DB<1> p unité
Unrecognized character \xC3; marked by <-- HERE after UT}   unit<-- HERE near column 119 at (eval 10)[/home/chris/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/5.32.0/perl5db.pl:738] line 2.
 at (eval 10)[/home/chris/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/5.32.0/perl5db.pl:738] line 2.
    eval 'no strict; ($@, $!, $^E, $,, $/, $\\, $^W) = @DB::saved;package main; $^D = $^D | $DB::db_stop;
print {$DB::OUT}   unité;
' called at /home/chris/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/5.32.0/perl5db.pl line 738
    DB::eval called at /home/chris/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/5.32.0/perl5db.pl line 3138
    DB::DB called at test.pl line 11

  DB<2> binmode($DB::IN, ':utf8');

  DB<3> p $unité    
125
  DB<4> 

You can use a .perldb file to always run code on startup in the debugger.
For example a .perldb file containing the following will  always switch your $DB::IN/OUT handles to utf-8:
sub afterinit{
    binmode($DB::IN, ':utf8');
    binmode($DB::OUT, ':utf8');
}

.perldb must not be writable by anyone except the owner (which has to be the current user). See the documentation.

Spot on ! I had not thought about the .perldb file. Thanks !
